# Function is called more then once for add observer for uikeyboard Did show Notification with different Observer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have one - one textfield in each 
 NSObjectClass(self,ObjectOne,ObjectTwo,ObjectThree) with delegate .
In viewDidLoad of `self class(uiviewController)` , I have add observer for each object class ..

Now here the problem starts , when I click on textfield , add observer method(keyboardWillAppear:) 
is called of each object `class(self, objectOne,ObjectTwo,ObjectThree)`

although at this time  textField is of objectOne. Please suggest where I am wrong and what are alternate of this .

[image]
[image: dd]

[image]

Comment: can please share your well formatted code ?

Comment: Remove observer, once you move away from the class.

Comment: well i am in same class m here my textfield are in different  nsobject class

Comment: I noticed that you have `reflect(self)` in your code, which probably means you're using an old version of Swift. This is won't help answer your question, but I highly recommend that you update Xcode. A lot of things have changed between Swift 1.2 and 2.2, and by asking a question using an older version of a language, you force potential answerers to think in a backward direction.

Comment: hi @VatsalManot my main question is in viewDidLoad for add observer

Comment: @vvss: Any potential answers will be forced to use an older syntax. Either that, or you end up with weird syntax errors.

Comment: @VatsalManot , i have four text field  in different  textfield . and their delegate are irrespective classes .. and  when i begin texting .. only that class jeyboadwill show be called by the nsbotifactioncenter . default

Comment: @vvss: I'm talking about the _syntax_.

Comment: well here that is not issue (reflect(self)) . here i am focus on how AddObserver is work